# Multiple databases on one SQL server with same table names. Two Linq to SQL Classes - Ambiguity error

Tags: linq-to-sql, datacontext

I'm trying to write a tool which will update a users account credentials across several databases. Each of these databases are basically supporting a different version of the same application so each database has the same table names. I'm only interested in one table called opususer on each of these databases.

I was able to create the first Linq to SQL class and using a checkbox list I create a collection of selected items and send it to a method which loops through and should update the user credentials. This works fine when I have one DataContext, but when I add another Linq to SQL class and try to recreate the same thing except on a different database I receive several Ambiguity errors and "The member is defined more than once" errors.

I don't understand as the LinqToSQL class is pointing to a completely different database although the table name is the same, but why should that matter as the datacontext should keep it separate no?

I've tried using one DataContext and also adding an alias, but I'm not sure if this can be done. I'm new to ASP.NET...

```
            if (DatabaseName == "clincomm_243x")
            {
                using (UserAccountDataContext Data = new UserAccountDataContext()) // database clincomm_243x
                {
                    string UserName = TextBoxUserName.Text.ToUpper();

                    opususer CheckUser = Data.opususers
                        .SingleOrDefault(opususer => opususer.username == UserName && opususer.active == true);
                    if (CheckUser == null || TextBoxUserName.Text.Length ==0)
                    {
                        TextBoxResult.Visible = true;
                        TextBoxResult.Text = "Username " + UserName + " does not exist. Please check and try again!";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        TextBoxResult.Text = "";
                        TextBoxResult.Text = "User " + UserName + " has been found.";
                        TextBoxResult.Visible = true;
                        TextBoxResult.Visible = true;
                        TextBoxResult.Text += "\nAttempting to update user account details.....\n";

                        // Set the new values for the record returned
                        CheckUser.password = "03ac674216f3e15c761ee1a5e255f067953623c8b388b4459e13f978d7c846f4";
                        CheckUser.hashtype_code = "SHA-256";
                        CheckUser.unsuccessfullogons = 0;
                        CheckUser.active = true;
                        DateTime newPasswordExpiryDate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddYears(10);
                        CheckUser.passwordexpirationdate = newPasswordExpiryDate;
                        Data.SubmitChanges();

                        TextBoxResult.Text += "\nUser Account " + UserName + " has been successfully updated\n";
                        TextBoxResult.Text += "\nPassword has now been set to 1234 and will not expire until " + newPasswordExpiryDate;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though you are using a new data context, the classes that represent your table(s) will reside in the same namespace - unless you specify a different namespace. Try giving unique namespaces to the "Entity Namespace" property for each of your DataContexts.

Comment: Awesome!!! Thanks so much for this information. From this I was able to figure out how to resolve my issue. I performed the following which got it working - Thanks a million, really helped me out thanks.
 
1. Open the *.dbml.
 
2. Click on the design surface - not on any of the entities.
 
3. Open the properties window.
 
4. Change Context Namespace and Entity Namespace properties to what you need them to be. (I named them both the same)
I then updated my using statement to prefix it with the new namespace

Comment: using (dbClincomm_2431.clincomm_2431DataContext Data = new dbClincomm_2431.clincomm_2431DataContext()) and then I updated the namespace for the table name dbClincomm_2431.opususer CheckUser = Data.opususers and that was it. It all started working fine. Many thanks again.